# Realtime object painting

Tags: c++, math, 3d, textures, irrlicht

I am trying to perform a realtime painting to the object texture. Using Irrlicht for now, but that does not really matter.

So far, i've got the right UV coordinates using this algorithm:

1. find out which object's triangle user selected (raycasting, nothing
   really difficult)
2. find out the UV (baricentric) coordinates of intersection point on
   that triangle
3. find out the UV (texture) coordinates of each triangle vertex
4. find out the UV (texture) coordinates of intersection point
5. calculate the texture image coordinates for intersection point

But somehow, when i am drawing in the point i got in the 5th step on texture image, i get totally wrong results. So, when drawing a rectangle in cursor point, the X (or Z) coordinate of its is inverted:

[image]

[image]

Here's the code i am using to fetch texture coordinates:

```
core::vector2df getPointUV(core::triangle3df tri, core::vector3df p)
{
    core::vector3df 
    v0 = tri.pointC - tri.pointA,
    v1 = tri.pointB - tri.pointA,
    v2 = p - tri.pointA;

    float dot00 = v0.dotProduct(v0),
    dot01 = v0.dotProduct(v1),
    dot02 = v0.dotProduct(v2),
    dot11 = v1.dotProduct(v1),
    dot12 = v1.dotProduct(v2);

    float invDenom = 1.f / ((dot00 * dot11) - (dot01 * dot01)),
    u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * invDenom,
    v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * invDenom;

    scene::IMesh* m = Mesh->getMesh(((scene::IAnimatedMeshSceneNode*)Model)->getFrameNr());

    core::array<video::S3DVertex> VA, VB, VC;
    video::SMaterial Material;

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < m->getMeshBufferCount(); i++)
    {
    scene::IMeshBuffer* mb = m->getMeshBuffer(i);
    video::S3DVertex* vertices = (video::S3DVertex*) mb->getVertices();

    for (unsigned long long v = 0; v < mb->getVertexCount(); v++)
    {
        if (vertices[v].Pos == tri.pointA)
        VA.push_back(vertices[v]); else
        if (vertices[v].Pos == tri.pointB)
        VB.push_back(vertices[v]); else
        if (vertices[v].Pos == tri.pointC)
        VC.push_back(vertices[v]);

        if (vertices[v].Pos == tri.pointA || vertices[v].Pos == tri.pointB || vertices[v].Pos == tri.pointC)
        Material = mb->getMaterial();

        if (VA.size() > 0 && VB.size() > 0 && VC.size() > 0)
        break;
    }

    if (VA.size() > 0 && VB.size() > 0 && VC.size() > 0)
        break;
    }

    core::vector2df 
    A = VA[0].TCoords,
    B = VB[0].TCoords,
    C = VC[0].TCoords;

    core::vector2df P(A + (u * (C - A)) + (v * (B - A)));
    core::dimension2du Size = Material.getTexture(0)->getSize();
    CursorOnModel = core::vector2di(Size.Width * P.X, Size.Height * P.Y);
    int X = Size.Width * P.X, Y = Size.Height * P.Y;

    // DRAWING SOME RECTANGLE    
    Material.getTexture(0)->lock(true);
    Device->getVideoDriver()->setRenderTarget(Material.getTexture(0), true, true, 0);
        Device->getVideoDriver()->draw2DRectangle(video::SColor(255, 0, 100, 75), core::rect<s32>((X - 10), (Y - 10), 
            (X + 10), (Y + 10)));
    Device->getVideoDriver()->setRenderTarget(0, true, true, 0);
    Material.getTexture(0)->unlock();

    return core::vector2df(X, Y);
}
```

I just wanna make my object paintable in realtime. My current problems are: **wrong texture coordinate calculation** and **non-unique vertex UV coordinates** (so, drawing something on the one side of the dwarfe's axe would draw the same on the other side of that axe).

How should i do this?

Comment: mmm...To have unique vertex UV coordinates you'll need to change the texture, copy the region modified and applying to the right tris with the new UV, Don't you ?

Comment: i think not. because first of all, i need to determine the painting region. and it requires unique UVs ;)

Comment: I found the repo and am glad for that, but please add a license. I thought maybe you switched to Ruby since I found moo3d but the program at the following URL looks correct: https://github.com/shybovycha/irrPaint3D Unless you add a license it is considered "no permission": https://choosealicense.com/no-permission/ (other than the snippets you and answerers pasted here which gets the stackoverflow license). The program is very useful since Blender crops brushstrokes inaccurately vs nearest pixel mode in Irrlicht such as for Minetest. A license will allow others to use and improve the program.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to use your codebase and get it to work for me.

**Re your second problem "non-unique vertex UV coordinates":**
Well you are absolutely right, you need unique vertexUVs to get this working, which means that you have to unwrap you models and don't make use of shared uv-space for e.g. mirrored elements and stuff. (e.g. left/right boot - if they use the same uv-space, you'll paint automatically on both, where you want the one to be red and the other to be green). You can check out "uvlayout" (tool) or the uv-unwrap modifier ind 3ds max.

**Re the first and more important problem: "**wrong texture coordinate calculation"**:
the calculation of your baycentric coordinates is correct, but as i suppose your input-data is wrong. I assume you get the triangle and the collisionPoint by using irrlicht's CollisionManager and TriangleSelector. The problem is, that the positions of the triangle's vertices (which you get as returnvalue from the collisionTest) is in WorldCoordiates. But you'll need them in ModelCoordinates for the calculation, so here's what you need to do:

*pseudocode*:

1. add the node which contains the mesh of the hit triangle as parameter to getPointUV()
2. get the inverse absoluteTransformation-Matrix by calling node->getAbsoluteTransformation() [inverse]
3. transform the vertices of the triangle by this inverse Matrix and use those values for the rest of the method.

Below you'll find my optimized method wich does it for a very simple mesh (one mesh, only one meshbuffer).

*Code:*

```
irr::core::vector2df getPointUV(irr::core::triangle3df tri, irr::core::vector3df p, irr::scene::IMeshSceneNode* pMeshNode, irr::video::IVideoDriver* pDriver)
{
    irr::core::matrix4 inverseTransform(
    pMeshNode->getAbsoluteTransformation(),
      irr::core::matrix4::EM4CONST_INVERSE);

    inverseTransform.transformVect(tri.pointA);
    inverseTransform.transformVect(tri.pointB);
    inverseTransform.transformVect(tri.pointC);

    irr::core::vector3df 
    v0 = tri.pointC - tri.pointA,
    v1 = tri.pointB - tri.pointA,
    v2 = p - tri.pointA;

    float dot00 = v0.dotProduct(v0),
    dot01 = v0.dotProduct(v1),
    dot02 = v0.dotProduct(v2),
    dot11 = v1.dotProduct(v1),
    dot12 = v1.dotProduct(v2);

    float invDenom = 1.f / ((dot00 * dot11) - (dot01 * dot01)),
    u = (dot11 * dot02 - dot01 * dot12) * invDenom,
    v = (dot00 * dot12 - dot01 * dot02) * invDenom;

    irr::video::S3DVertex A, B, C;
    irr::video::S3DVertex* vertices = static_cast<irr::video::S3DVertex*>(
      pMeshNode->getMesh()->getMeshBuffer(0)->getVertices());

    for(unsigned int i=0; i < pMeshNode->getMesh()->getMeshBuffer(0)->getVertexCount(); ++i)
    {
      if( vertices[i].Pos == tri.pointA)
      {
        A = vertices[i];
      }
      else if( vertices[i].Pos == tri.pointB)
      {
        B = vertices[i];
      }
      else if( vertices[i].Pos == tri.pointC)
      {
        C = vertices[i];
      }
    }

    irr::core::vector2df t2 = B.TCoords - A.TCoords;
    irr::core::vector2df t1 = C.TCoords - A.TCoords;

    irr::core::vector2df uvCoords = A.TCoords + t1*u + t2*v;

    return uvCoords;
}
```

Comment: I have adopted a similar approach with representing vectors as a sum of other two vectors (all in context of a single triangle) and since vectors are relative, there is no need for inverse matrix (or any other matrix) transformations (yay!). Briefly described the approach on my blog https://shybovycha.github.io/2021/05/04/irr-paint-3d.html#the-maths-behind